Json com nó dinamico
Boas pessoal,
Gostaria de uma ajuda no entendimento de como resolver a questão abaixo.
Tenho este arquivo JSON com a seguinte estrutura :
    {
    "timezone": "UTC",
    "serverTime": 1721749956454,
    "rateLimits": [{
            "rateLimitType": "REQUEST_WEIGHT",
            "interval": "MINUTE",
            "intervalNum": 1,
            "limit": 6000
        }, {
            "rateLimitType": "ORDERS",
            "interval": "SECOND",
            "intervalNum": 10,
            "limit": 100
        }, {
            "rateLimitType": "ORDERS",
            "interval": "DAY",
            "intervalNum": 1,
            "limit": 200000
        }, {
            "rateLimitType": "RAW_REQUESTS",
            "interval": "MINUTE",
            "intervalNum": 5,
            "limit": 61000
        }
    ],
    "exchangeFilters": [],
    "   ": [{
            "symbol": "ETHBTC",
            "status": "TRADING",
            "baseAsset": "ETH",
            "baseAssetPrecision": 8,
            "quoteAsset": "BTC",
            "quotePrecision": 8,
            "quoteAssetPrecision": 8,
            "baseCommissionPrecision": 8,
            "quoteCommissionPrecision": 8,
            "orderTypes": ["LIMIT", "LIMIT_MAKER", "MARKET", "STOP_LOSS", "STOP_LOSS_LIMIT", "TAKE_PROFIT", "TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT"],
            "icebergAllowed": true,
            "ocoAllowed": true,
            "otoAllowed": true,
            "quoteOrderQtyMarketAllowed": true,
            "allowTrailingStop": true,
            "cancelReplaceAllowed": true,
            "isSpotTradingAllowed": true,
            "isMarginTradingAllowed": true,
            "filters": [{
                    "filterType": "PRICE_FILTER",
                    "minPrice": "0.00001000",
                    "maxPrice": "922327.00000000",
                    "tickSize": "0.00001000"
                }, {
                    "filterType": "LOT_SIZE",
                    "minQty": "0.00010000",
                    "maxQty": "100000.00000000",
                    "stepSize": "0.00010000"
                }, {
                    "filterType": "ICEBERG_PARTS",
                    "limit": 10
                }, {
                    "filterType": "MARKET_LOT_SIZE",
                    "minQty": "0.00000000",
                    "maxQty": "3605.02895020",
                    "stepSize": "0.00000000"
                }, {
                    "filterType": "TRAILING_DELTA",
                    "minTrailingAboveDelta": 10,
                    "maxTrailingAboveDelta": 2000,
                    "minTrailingBelowDelta": 10,
                    "maxTrailingBelowDelta": 2000
                }, {
                    "filterType": "PERCENT_PRICE_BY_SIDE",
                    "bidMultiplierUp": "5",
                    "bidMultiplierDown": "0.2",
                    "askMultiplierUp": "5",
                    "askMultiplierDown": "0.2",
                    "avgPriceMins": 5
                }, {
                    "filterType": "NOTIONAL",
                    "**minNotional**": "0.00010000",
                    "applyMinToMarket": true,
                    "maxNotional": "9000000.00000000",
                    "applyMaxToMarket": false,
                    "avgPriceMins": 5
                }, {
                    "filterType": "MAX_NUM_ORDERS",
                    "maxNumOrders": 200
                }, {
                    "filterType": "MAX_NUM_ALGO_ORDERS",
                    "maxNumAlgoOrders": 5
                }
            ],

Estou usando o seguinte código para leitura.

 Arquivo := TStringList.Create;
  Arquivo.LoadFromFile
    ('c:\JSON\tb_tmp2.json');

  Json := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Arquivo.Text), 0)
    as TJSONObject;
  Item := Json.GetValue<TJSONArray>('symbols');

  for i := 0 to Item.size - 1 do
  begin
    showmessage(Item[i].GetValue<string>('symbol')); // OK
    showmessage(Item[i].GetValue<string>('filters[0].filterType')); // OK
    showmessage(Item[i].GetValue<string>('filters[6].minNotional'));
  end;

  Json.DisposeOf;

Este código está funcionando bem, porém existe um detalhe que está dificultando a leitura do arquivo, que refere-se ao campo / tag minNotional, pois a posição dele não é fixa dentro da estrutura do JSON,hora ele está na posição 6, hora na posição 5, ou outra posição.
Dai quando a leitura do JSON é executada, e ocorre do minNotional não estar na posição 6, dá exceção no código.
Isto também gera uma falha de inclusão no banco de dados, pois monto um SQL para inserir.
Acredito que o que preciso, é de alguma forma, em vez de ler a posição do index do nó,ler seu nome, não sei como resolver isso.
Agradeço desde já.

Voce ja faz um parse com o Json e depois com o symbols/Item, faz mais um com o filters

veja se o exemplo aqui ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75100774/i-want-to-check-if-there-is-a-specific-key-in-the-json-object

Você precisa Iterar sobre os elementos do array "filters" até encontrar aquele em que o filterType é "NOTIONAL". Depois Obtém o valor de minNotional desse filtro, se encontrado, e exibe uma mensagem.
Se o minNotional não for encontrado, exibe uma mensagem informativa.
Veja o código abaixo:
var
  Arquivo: TStringList;
  Json, Item, Filter: TJSONObject;
  SymbolsArray, FiltersArray: TJSONArray;
  i, j: Integer;
  MinNotional: string;
begin
  Arquivo := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Arquivo.LoadFromFile('c:\JSON\tb_tmp2.json');

    // Parse o JSON
    Json := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Arquivo.Text), 0) as TJSONObject;
    try
      SymbolsArray := Json.GetValue<TJSONArray>('symbols');

      for i := 0 to SymbolsArray.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Item := SymbolsArray.Items[i] as TJSONObject;

        // Obtenha e exiba o símbolo
        ShowMessage(Item.GetValue<string>('symbol'));

        // Obtenha o array de filtros para o símbolo
        FiltersArray := Item.GetValue<TJSONArray>('filters');

        // Inicialize a variável de MinNotional como vazia
        MinNotional := '';

        // Itere sobre os filtros para encontrar o 'NOTIONAL'
        for j := 0 to FiltersArray.Count - 1 do
        begin
          Filter := FiltersArray.Items[j] as TJSONObject;

          if Filter.GetValue<string>('filterType') = 'NOTIONAL' then
          begin
            MinNotional := Filter.GetValue<string>('minNotional');
            Break; // Encerra o loop assim que encontrar o filtro desejado
          end;
        end;

        // Verifica se encontrou o minNotional e exibe
        if MinNotional <> '' then
          ShowMessage(MinNotional)
        else
          ShowMessage('minNotional não encontrado para o símbolo ' + Item.GetValue<string>('symbol'));
      end;

    finally
      Json.Free;
    end;

  finally
    Arquivo.Free;
  end;
end;

